# How to get all meta value of a post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a code to get all meta data of a particular post type cef_donor

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'cef_donor',
);
$posts_array = get_posts($arg);

$metaData = array();
foreach($posts_array as $key => $value){
    $metaData[] = get_post_meta($value->ID,'', true);
}
```

When I print $metaData I get array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => Array  (
                    [0] => value one
                )
            [meta_key_two] => Array
                (
                    [0] => value two
                )
            [meta_key_three] => Array
                (
                    [0] => value three
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => Array  (
                    [0] => another value one
                )
            [meta_key_two] => Array
                (
                    [0] => another value two
                )
            [meta_key_three] => Array
                (
                    [0] => another value three
                )
        )
)
```

But I just need an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => value one
            [meta_key_two] => value two
            [meta_key_three] => value three
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => another value one
            [meta_key_two] => another value two
            [meta_key_three] => another value three
        )
)
```

Is there any other easy way to get all meta_key and its meta_value of a post type.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new one. Loop the old value to the new one. Consider this example:

```
$metaData = array( array( 'meta_key_one' => array('value_one'), 'meta_key_two' => array('value_two'), 'meta_key_three' => array('value_three'), ), array( 'meta_key_one' => array('another_value_one'), 'meta_key_two' => array('another_value_two'), 'meta_key_three' => array('another_value_three'), ),);
$new_values = array();
foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $index => $element) {
        $new_values[$key][$index] = $element[0];
    }
}

print_r($new_values);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => value_one
            [meta_key_two] => value_two
            [meta_key_three] => value_three
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_key_one] => another_value_one
            [meta_key_two] => another_value_two
            [meta_key_three] => another_value_three
        )

)
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AloS3T)

Comment: Thanks for reply,
meta_key_one, meta_key_two, meta_key_three are may be vary, or there will be another array key with meta_key_four_my_address, school_name like anyhing etc.
I am considering it as a field name of a form.

Comment: hello @Dinoop if the keys if going to be dynamic, then you can check my edit. good day :)

Comment: Thank you @kevinabelita, Its working :). Do we have any other wordpress function like get_post_meta  to get the meta data directly like this?

Comment: @Dinoop Your welcome :) In all honesty no I havent checked the codex if a function does with this capability exists. Good day